# std(boost)::filesystem::path number of components

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-filesystem

Is there any idiomatic way to get number of components in a path using filesystem library? Or have I missed some method for this?

Or do I have to, like, call `parent_path()` until I get to the root?

Comment: What do you plan to do with that number of components? Because if you're going to iterate over them, there are easier ways. Such as using *iterators*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `size()` method?

```
boost::filesystem::path p;
// fill p
std::cout << p.size() << std::endl;
```

will give you the number of components.

Also `path` iterators don't iterate over the string of the path, but over the components of the path. So this should work too:

```
std::distance(p.begin(), p.end());
```

Comment: Maybe you're aware, does `size()` exist in the `std::` version of filesystem? Don't see it immediately on cppreference

Comment: @ledonter Actually I haven't used the `std` version yet. But I use the `boost` version quite often. I never had the luxary of using C++17 professionally, yet.

Comment: I don't think there is a `size()` in C++17.  It could perhaps be added; my understanding is that the implementation benefits from knowing the number of components.  But note that it would count any root-name, root-directory, and trailing empty components...

Comment: More to the point: `boost::filesystem::path::size()` [counts characters, not components](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-size).